# CARPET driver creates errors

Tags: c++, git, cygwin, toolkit

I am using [Einstein toolkit](https://einsteintoolkit.org/) on Windows via Cygwin.

When I use carpet driver, I have found errors because of HDF5 library.

I installed following packages;

curl,perl,subversion,git,gcc-{core,fortran,g++},make,patch,libjpeg-devel,openssl-devel,xgraph,vim.

It's working well with [PUGH](https://einsteintoolkit.org/thornguide/CactusPUGH/PUGH/documentation.html) but [CARPET](https://www.carpetcode.org/) is not working.
Kindly,tell me how I can fix it.

The errors:

```
/home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/build/CarpetLib/limits.cc: 
  In function ‘void CarpetLib::set_system_limits()’: 
  /home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/build/CarpetLib/limits.cc:27:13: 
  error: ‘RLIMIT_RSS’ was not declared in this scope set_limit(RLIMIT_RSS, "resident set size", max_memory_size_MB); 
 /home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/build/CarpetLib/limits.cc:27:13: 
 note: suggested alternative: ‘RLIMIT_AS’ set_limit(RLIMIT_RSS, "resident set size", max_memory_size_MB); 

Running configuration script for thorn MPI: 
  MPI selected, but MPI_DIR is not set. 
Computing settings... Found MPI compiler wrapper at /usr/bin/mpic++! Successfully configured MPI. 
Finished running configuration script for thorn MPI.

make[3]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/config-data/make.config.rules:281: limits.cc.o] Error 1 
make[2]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/lib/make/make.thornlib:113: make.checked] Error 2 
make[1]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/lib/make/make.configuration:179: /home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/lib/libthorn_CarpetLib.a] Error 2 
make: *** [Makefile:263: carpet] Error 2
```

Comment: Could you update your question with what you sent me as an email? I only answer here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please! Sir now guide me.........

Comment: What Windows do you have? (type winver in a CMD shell session)

Comment: What error message do you get? The ones you previously mentioned were warning (non-blocking).

Comment: Running configuration script for thorn MPI:
MPI selected, but MPI_DIR is not set. Computing settings...
Found MPI compiler wrapper at /usr/bin/mpic++!
Successfully configured MPI.
Finished running configuration script for thorn MPI.

Comment: make[3]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/config-data/make.config.rules:281: limits.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/lib/make/make.thornlib:113: make.checked] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/lib/make/make.configuration:179: /home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/lib/libthorn_CarpetLib.a] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:263: carpet] Error 2

Comment: For testing, can you follow https://docs.einsteintoolkit.org/et-docs/Simplified_Tutorial_for_New_Users (not directly using CARPET) just to see if that part is working?

Comment: yes.I have done examples like wavetoy, brill wave. but once i use any module with carpet instead of PUGH. it's not working.

Comment: Is there any other error messages before the make/Error lines? (see as an example of possible errors http://lists.einsteintoolkit.org/pipermail/users/2019-August/006981.html)

Comment: /home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/build/CarpetLib/limits.cc: In function ‘void CarpetLib::set_system_limits()’:
/home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/build/CarpetLib/limits.cc:27:13: error: ‘RLIMIT_RSS’ was not declared in this scope
   set_limit(RLIMIT_RSS, "resident set size", max_memory_size_MB);
             ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/hp/cactus/configs/carpet/build/CarpetLib/limits.cc:27:13: note: suggested alternative: ‘RLIMIT_AS’
   set_limit(RLIMIT_RSS, "resident set size", max_memory_size_MB);

Comment: Running configuration script for thorn MPI:
MPI selected, but MPI_DIR is not set. Computing settings...

Comment: Did you try the suggested alternative listed in the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

This was [reported in 2013](http://lists.einsteintoolkit.org/pipermail/users/2013-July/003117.html):

> The warnings that are reported are harmless, since the content of the file does not matter -- what only matters is that there is at least one file generated when the self-test succeeds.
>
> In general, scheduling a routine into a non-existing schedule bin means that this routine is not executed.
> In many cases, this is just the right thing to do. In other cases, this is e.g. due to an error in `schedule.ccl`, which is why we moved from "silently not scheduling" to reporting warnings about these.
> In this case, the warnings are harmless and no need to worry, since the thorns Boundary and SymBase are not actually required by CartGrid3D. One wishes there was a way to indicate this in the `schedule.ccl` so that these warnings could be omitted.

Regarding the use of CARPET, et the errors related to HDF5, here are all the [current issues for the component CARPET with HDF5 in its description](https://bitbucket.org/einsteintoolkit/tickets/issues?component=Carpet&content=%7EHDF5)

A similar error was [seen in this thread](http://lists.einsteintoolkit.org/pipermail/users/2019-August/006981.html).
It illustrates that the error messages *before* the make/Error lines could help knowing what is going on.